# Why are the cargo doors of the C2 Greyhound open during flight, even when not delivering cargo?

Tags: military, turboprop

You may find this strange, but I have a love for the C2 Greyhound and E2C Hawkeye. I noticed that when flying, the C2 Greyhound often opens its cargo doors. Is this for a better view, training, or other reasons? Thank you.

Comment: Where have you observed this?

Comment: This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAGEu_X_zoo

Comment: And this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48jZgc1-O-o

Comment: It's clear in both those videos that the doors are opened for the benefit of the cameras. I don't think you need look further than that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Linus. I would point out that two videos do not constitute "often", but rather "sometimes" :) Youtube and other such media seldom present run of the mill operations, the usually focus on some kind of special shenanigans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that they just did this for air to air photography. I just did some research, and the only reason I could find was for airdrops.